# undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'

Tags: llvm

I am compiling llvm 14 using the following CMAKE command:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/me/data/programs/llvm14/llvm-install-release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;clang-tools-extra;libunwind;lldb;lld;compiler-rt;polly;" -DLLVM_ENABLE_RUNTIMES="libcxx;libcxxabi" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_USE_SPLIT_DWARF=ON -DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON -DLLVM_INSTALL_UTILS=ON -DLLVM_ENABLE_RTTI=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON  -DLLVM_ENABLE_ABI_BREAKING_CHECKS=OFF ../llvm
```

But I get the following error when compiling LLVM 14.

gtest-all.cc:(.text._ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv[_ZNK7testing8internal11ThreadLocalIPNS_31TestPartResultReporterInterfaceEE16GetOrCreateValueEv]+0xd): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'

clang-14: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

It seems that gtest need pthread.

How to resolve this error?

My system is:
Ubuntu 18.04
gcc 11.4.0
X86 CPU

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but I remember that the documenation suggests that `-G Ninja` is what they expect people to use and other generators might have issues, did you have the same problem with that?

Comment: I use Ninja and succeed. Thanks.